# How do I uninstall Kinect Fun Labs?

Tags: xbox-360, kinect, kinect-fun-labs

Please tell me how to uninstall Kinect Fun Labs. I tried going to my storage to delete it, buy it said, "There was a problem performing that action." And I tried going to where I downloaded it, and it didn't say delete or anything! Does it stay on your Xbox forever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE:** Kinect Fun Labs have some problems to install/uninstall

Try to uninstall using one of these two methods:

**From Home hub**

> 1. From the Home hub, select the game, and then press Y
> 2. Select Delete

**From System Settings**

> 1. Go to the Settings hub, and choose System
> 2. Select Storage
> 3. Select Hard Drive
> 4. Select the game that you want to delete
> 5. Select Delete

[Source](http://support.xbox.com/en-GB/xbox-360/audio-video-setup-and-use/install-play-delete-game)

Comment: > have some problems to install/uninstall - you got that right;)